# Fill ExpandableListAdapter with SQLite

Tags: java, android, list, sqlite, hashmap

I've been trying for almost a day to fix this problem but I cannot figure out what is wrong.

I got this code

```
private void someFunction() {       

    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    List<String> tempNomoi = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<GeneralInfo> diamerismata = db.getAllDiamerismata();
    List<GeneralInfo> nomoi = new ArrayList<GeneralInfo>();

    for (GeneralInfo a : diamerismata) {
        listDataHeader.add(a.getDiamerisma());

        nomoi = db.GetNomousDiamerismatos(a.getDiamerisma());

        tempNomoi.clear();

        for (GeneralInfo b : nomoi) {

            tempNomoi.add(b.getNomo());

        }

        listDataChild.put(a.getDiamerisma(), tempNomoi);
        System.out.println(listDataChild);
    }

}
```

And I get this output

```
I/System.out(5750): SELECT nomos FROM info WHERE diamerisma = 'diamerisma1'

I/System.out(5750): {diamerisma1=[nomos1, nomos3, nomos5]}

I/System.out(5750): SELECT nomos FROM info WHERE diamerisma = 'diamerisma2'

I/System.out(5750): {diamerisma2=[nomos2, nomos4], diamerisma1=[nomos2, nomos4]}

I/System.out(5750): SELECT nomos FROM info WHERE diamerisma = 'diamerisma3'

I/System.out(5750): {diamerisma2=[nomos6], diamerisma3=[nomos6], diamerisma1=[nomos6]}
```

(the select statements come from the functions responsible for managing the queries)

As you can see from the output, after each loop the values are getting overwriten by the new ones... I wanted to have `{diamerisma1=[nomos1, nomos3, nomos5], diamerisma2=[nomos2, nomos4],  diamerisma3=[nomos6]}`

Maybe there is something I miss about how HashMaps work... I would really appreciate if someone could point out where I am wrong

Thanks in advance and thanks for reading!

Comment: `Maybe there is something I miss about how HashMaps work` rather not ... it seems like you are missing the point that not creating new object is not creating new object(so you are using the same - `tempNomoi` instance)

Comment: @Selvin So you are saying I would need as many objects as the size of listDataHeader for the Hashmap to work?

Comment: hmmm, no, i think you should create new instance of tempNomoi instead of clearing it inside the loop ... because now you add the same instance but with the different keys (to the listDataChild hashmap)

Comment: @Selvin That worked! Thanks a lot! You truly saved me a lot of time, I would never think of that!

Answer (score 0):

Hi below code some help for you

```
  View.OnClickListener listOnClick = new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
       favoriteList = db.getFavList();
       listView.setAdapter(new ViewAdapter());
      }
     };

//Get FavList
 public List<FavoriteList> getFavList(){
  String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TEST;
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
  List<FavoriteList> FavList = new ArrayList<FavoriteList>();
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
    FavoriteList list = new FavoriteList();
    list.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    list.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    list.setAge(cursor.getString(2));
    FavList.add(list);
   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
  return FavList;
 }
```

If you need more detail please see below link
http://mylearnandroid.blogspot.in/2014/04/android-sqlite-with-custom-listview.html

Comment: Well that didn't really help on my problem since I know how to populate my lists... I am just stuck with that HashMap!